# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ibm.watson.discovery.v1.Discovery.getServiceUrl()

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-discovery

I am using very simple code :

```
import com.ibm.cloud.sdk.core.security.IamAuthenticator;
import com.ibm.watson.discovery.v1.Discovery;
public class DiscoveryTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    IamAuthenticator authenticator = new IamAuthenticator("<KEY>");
    Discovery discovery = new Discovery("2018-08-01",authenticator);

    discovery.setEndPoint("https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/discovery/api/");
    System.out.println(discovery.getName());
}

}
```

POM :

```
com.ibm.watson
ibm-watson
8.0.0


com.ibm.cloud
sdk-core
7.0.0-rc1
```

Error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.ibm.watson.discovery.v1.Discovery.getServiceUrl()Ljava/lang/String;
at com.ibm.watson.discovery.v1.Discovery.(Discovery.java:158)
at com.ibm.tsc.dashbrd.DiscoveryTest.main(DiscoveryTest.java:12)
```

Why there is no method called getServiceUrl() in Discovery or super class ?

Comment: NoSuchMethodError looks like incompatible jar files

Answer (score -1):

I was using the wrong SDK version.

After upgrading to Watson Java SDK 8.0.0, the problem was resolved.